# Finding Duplicates based On A Property In Object

Tags: vb.net, linq

I want to check for duplicates based on a field in an object.

I have an object called Item that has 3 properties

```
ID
Rank
Name
```

I have a list of type Item in a container called

```
lstTheItems
```

I am using this code to check for duplicates

```
'lstTheItems IS NOT CORRECT
 Dim duplicates = lstTheItems.GroupBy(Function(i) i) _
                                .Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1) _
                                .[Select](Function(g) g.Key)
```

How do I return duplicate items base on the Name property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim duplicates = svgGrpContainer.Select(Function(x) svgGrpContainer.Count(Function(y)) > 1));
```

This means that we will select all the elements which appear more than once in the svgGrpContainer.

`Function(x)` = one element of svgGrpContainer

`svgGrpContainer.Count` = go through all the elements getting the count of..

`Function(y) > 1` = means that we will take all the element which appear more than once

I hope this helps

Comment: maybe you could add some explanation of your solution, specifiucally what the questioner was missing or doing wrong, and how your answer solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to group it by the `Name`, no the object itself.  Also, you probably want to get the entire object back in your duplicate list, not just the key (in this case the name).

```
Dim duplicates = lstTheItems.GroupBy(Function(i) i.Name) _
                            .Where(Function(x) x.Count() > 1) _
                            .[Select](Function(x) x)
```

Comment: I get an exception that Lambda parameter 'g' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or implicitly declared variable in query expression

Comment: See update.  `g` is the default grouping variable after a `GroupBy` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim duplicates = svgGrpContainer.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Name).Where(Function(x) x.Count > 1).Select(Function(x) x)
```