# Count duplicates of object property in list

Tags: vb.net

I've spent all afternoon looking for the answer to this one and not had any luck.

I have an object declared, and of that it has a number of properties. e.g.

```
Public Class myObject
    Private _prop1 As String
    Private _prop2 As String
    Private _prop3 As String
    Private _prop4 As String


    Public Sub New(ByVal val1 As String _
           , ByVal val2 As String _
           , ByVal val3 As String _
           , ByVal val4 As String)
    _prop1 = val1
    _prop2 = val2
    _prop3 = val3
    _prop4 = val4
    End Sub

    Public Property Prop1() As String
    Get
        Return _prop1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _prop1 = value
    End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Prop2() As String
    Get
        Return _prop2
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _prop2 = value
    End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Prop3() As String
    Get
        Return _prop3
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _prop3 = value
    End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Prop4() As String
    Get
        Return _prop4
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _prop4 = value
    End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Within my code I have as list of these object:

```
Dim myList as List(of myObject)
```

I then populate the list...

{as requested, it's a bit like this, even though the method of populating it is irrelevant :-)}

```
Dim myFile as String = readFile(myFilename)
Dim fileLines() as String = Split(myFile,vbCrLf)
Dim splitLine() as String
For each line in fileLines
    splitLine = Split(line,"|")
    myList.add(new myObject(splitLine(0),splitLine(1),splitLine(2),splitLine(3))
 Next
```

What I need is a list where all Prop1 values are unique, so I want to be able to identify any duplicate values in myList.Prop1

I've tried [Finding Duplicates based On A Property In Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973495/finding-duplicates-based-on-a-property-in-object) but that doesn't seem to illicit anything.

I deliberately created the list with one known duplicate. Using the adapted code from the above question...

```
Dim duplicates = myList.GroupBy(Function(i) i.Prop1) _
                        .Where(Function(x) x.Count() > 1) _
                        .[Select](Function(x) x)
```

... results in duplicates being "nothing", even though there is one.

At this stage I don't need to identify the duplicates, just the fact that they are there. However, if it's straightforward to incorporate this functionality than I would like to add this in.

Comment: Can you share the code where you populate the objects?

Comment: The duplicates query code works fine - it is returning collections of items with the same property value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward to get all duplicate objects, take a look at this example:

```
Dim myList as List(Of myObject) = New List(Of myObject)

'Add arbitrary values (demo only)
myList.AddRange({New myObject("A", "B", "C", "D"), New myObject("A", "C", "D", "E"), New myObject("B", "C", "D", "E"), New myObject("C", "D", "E", "F")})

'Get all objects where Prop1 is the same
Dim duplicateProp1 = (From o As myObject in myList Group By Prop1 = o.Prop1 Into g = Group Where g.Count > 1 Select g.FirstOrDefault())

'Print all the duplicate objects (demo only)
For Each d As myObject In duplicateProp1
    Console.WriteLine(d.Prop1)
Next
```

Fiddle: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dj79UH)

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for this. Works a treat!